# My exsisting Google Cloud Prject does not show up in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

I have an existing Google Cloud Project as can be seen:[Google Cloud Project List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbC5w.png) by the name IIMA Student App. I want to integrate the same app over at Firebase, however I have run out of number of free Firebase App so I was hoping to add the IIMA Student App as an existing App but it does not show up in the list. The picture at Firebase is as [Firebase Console Project List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MydwH.png). My primary goal is to use Google Auth2.0 for creating a Login in my Android App so as to only allow custom domain(eg: user@mydomain.com) to only log in to my app.

Comment: It may require a deeper look into your projects to investigate. I suggest to go to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) to get better help on the issue.